# How to use firebase storage with NodeJs on server side

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to use firebase storage on server side, but when I am trying to create a ref, it gives an error.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require('../ServiceAccountKey.json');
const firebaseAdmin = admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: ...
    storageBucket: ...
});
const db = admin.firestore();
const storage = admin.storage();

router.post('/editorJS/uploads',  (req, res) => {
    let b = req.body;
    let arrayBuffer = b.buffer.slice(b.byteOffset, b.byteOffset + b.byteLength);
    
    let blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer]);

    console.log("check1");
    var storageRef = storage.ref();
    console.log("check2");
    storageRef.put(blob).then(snapshot => {
        console.log("Uploaded a file or blob");
    })
});
```

I am following official docs. Still, it gives an error. Using console.log gives an idea that which line gives the error.

```
check1
Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory "F:\newProject\upStair\functions\views"
```

Comment: the error has to do with a res.render call, not this code most likely

Comment: code runs from top to bottom. So, first it must logs to the console "check2" and "Uploaded a file or blob". But this is not the case

Comment: what happens if you put storageRef= code outside the post route entirely and just try to start the app up?

Comment: `TypeError: admin.storage(...).ref is not a function`

Comment: oh thats your main problem then. the error failed to look up views is happening AS its trying to report the error. i didnt notice that the error message was looking for the "error" view before.

Comment: you probably have a view engine configured in app.js which expects to have a views folder and error.(extension) where extension is .pug or .hbs or .ejs depending on what view enging (did you use express-generator? it handles this for you)